# Make a jQuery slider work with divs instead of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slideshow

I am working on this website page [poochclub.com](http://www.poochclub.com/about) and I am trying to make all of it text instead of images. The problem is when I want to work on the panels below with all the information the js file (called about.js) is set to work with images instead on divs where I could potentially add text.
I am not very good at writing javascript and I need help to fix the original file which looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript>        
(function ($) {
         var pages, panels, arrows, currentClass = 'current', 
          currentIndex = 0, currentSize = 0;

    function showPage() {
        var ctx = jQuery.trim(this.className.replace(/current/gi, ''));
        $(this).addClass(currentClass).siblings().removeClass(currentClass);

        $('.panel')
            .removeClass(currentClass)
            .find('img')
                .removeClass(currentClass)
                .removeAttr('style')
            .end();

        panels.find('.' + ctx)          
            .addClass(currentClass)
            .find('img')    
                .removeClass(currentClass)
                .removeAttr('style')    
                .eq(0)
                    .fadeIn()
                    .addClass(currentClass)
            .end()      

        currentIndex = 0;
        currentSize = panels.find('.' + ctx + ' img').length;
        return false;
    }

    function showArrows(e) {
        arrows['fade' + (e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 'In' : 'Out')]();
    }

    function getPrev() {
        currentIndex = currentIndex - 1 < 0 ? currentSize - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
        return currentIndex;
    }

    function doPrev() {
        var ctx = panels.find('div.current img');
        ctx.removeClass(currentClass).removeAttr('style');
        ctx.eq(getPrev()).fadeIn().addClass(currentClass);
    }

    function getNext() {
        currentIndex = currentIndex + 1 >= currentSize ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
        return currentIndex;    
    }

    function doNext() {
        var ctx = panels.find('div.current img');
        ctx.removeClass(currentClass).removeAttr('style');
        ctx.eq(getNext()).fadeIn().addClass(currentClass);  
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        pages = $('.panels-nav a');
        panels = $('.panels');  
        arrows = $('.arrows');

        pages.click(showPage);
        panels.bind('mouseenter mouseleave', showArrows);
        arrows.find('.prev').click(doPrev).end().find('.next').click(doNext);

        pages.eq(0).click();
    });
});
</script>
```

My questions is, how do I change the js file from finding img to finding several different div id's attached to the sliding panles?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any specific question?

Answer (score 0):

any reference to img should be a new selector. Something like 'div.slider', a div with a class slider.

Look at all the finds, thats where you will see the img selectors.